# How to add WPF support to .NET 5 Winforms project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-5

I'm converting an old .NET Framework 4 WinForms application to .NET 5. In this case, the easiest way was to re-create the project, which mostly worked. However, I have a method to decode a JPG image from a memory stream:

```
            // Look for JFIF header
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream( rawData );
            JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder( memStream,
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default );
            BitmapSource bmpSource = decoder.Frames[0];
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap( bmpSource.PixelWidth, bmpSource.PixelHeight,
                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb );
```

This fails because VS 2019 complains that "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging" causes an error, and JpegBitmapDecoder shows with a red squiggly. If I hover over JpegBitmapDecoder, I'm given the option for "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; from PresentationCode".

However, choosing that causes VS 2019 to be stuck on "Execute Suggested Action", trying to add the using.

The project is targeted for .NET 5, and I've added the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility NuGet package, so what am I doing wrong? Or, how to I access the JpegBitmapDecoder?

Comment: `var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(rawData), true);`. Or do you have a good reason to use a BitmapSource in WinForms?

Comment: It's a section of bytes from a DICOM .dcm file that can either be in JPG or BMP format. At the time, having 2 separate methods (the easy one for BMP and the JPG-specific one) seemed like the only way to decode it. Are you saying just Image.FromStream() will handle this correctly, whichever format the byte stream is?

Comment: Yes, it generates a Bitmap (if the Image format is supported, of course), using the internal decoder derived from the source Bitmap header. If your DICOMs are 16bit Grayscale Images, of course it won't work.

Comment: Btw, add this information to the question, it can be more useful to others. If the DICOM format is not supported by GDI+ and this is the reason why a BitmatSource was used in the first place, it would be good for someone else to find this information.

Comment: Jimi, DICOM is a file format, not an image format, so it's not a GDI+ issue. It does contain an image that can be in various formats, and that's where I ran into this. As I mention below, this was inherited code. I should fix that to use only GDI+ and now WPF.

Comment: I know what a DICOM is. With *If the DICOM format is not supported by GDI+* I of course referring to the Image format the DICOM contains. Since this format often uses 16bit grayscale images and can store multi-frame Images, these formats are not supported by GDI+, which could explain why the more *flexible* BitmapSource and the PresentationFramework's Decoder were used. If that's the case, you cannot use GDI+ to decode the images.

Answer (score 6):

<s>You write that you're using Visual Studio 2019 (e.g. version 16.7.6). However, as far as I know, .NET 5 projects are supported only in Visual Studio 2019 Preview (i.e. version 16.8.0 Preview).</s>

Note: .NET 5 projects are supported only in version 16.8.0 of Visual Studio 2019 and later (I only just realized that the "Preview" had made it to released status).

When I try to reproduce your problem in Visual Studio 2019 Preview, I get a slightly different issue: when I select the *"using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; from PresentationCode"* menu item, a progress dialog shows up:

[image: "using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; (from PresentationCore)" progress dialog]

This dialog seems to go on forever. Visual Studio never seems to actually complete the action.

So that part of the feature seems broken. However, fortunately you can do the same thing manually that Visual Studio should have done for you. Simply select the project, and then choose *"Edit Project File"* from the *"Project"* menu, and add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to the main project `<PropertyGroup>` element.

When you're done, the project file might look something like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

At that point, the entry *"Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms"* under the *"Frameworks"* item in the project's *"Dependencies"* WPF libraries should change to *"Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"* and will include both the Winforms and WPF libraries that you need.

You can go the other way as well, adding Winforms support to an existing WPF project, simply by adding the `<UseWindowsForms/>` element instead.

Of course, this all begs the question why you don't just use the GDI+ image handling types. Winforms can load JPEG files just as well as WPF, so why you want the dependency on WPF is unclear. But there are other reasons to mix and match too. Whatever the reason you want to combine Winforms and WPF in a .NET 5 project, the above will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apparently, I have to add a UseWPF item in the project file, since PresentationCore is really a WPF library. Doing so fixed the problem.

Comment: this is stack overflow.....  its ok to answer your own question, when answering your own question make it like a normal answer......  ie, ditch the "Never mind"  the whole point is someone else might find an answer useful also! :)