# Cant add wmp.dll reference to C# .Net Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll, visual-studio-2019

I am building simple media player, written in c#. It's Windows Forms app and by `.csproj` file my target framework is `net5.0-windows`.

I want to use wmp.dll.

The problem is, Visual Studio 2019 shows me an error message "The reference is invalid or unsupported". I got this when via solution explorrer added a reference to wmp.dll.

wmp.dll is located in my PC in C:\Windows\System32 directory.

I also tried to download wmp.dll using nuget package. When I done this I have got the following code in `.csproj` file

```
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Up3.5" Version="1.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="WMPLib" Version="1.0.0">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

And still I can not use WMPLib in my project.
I appreciate any help.

***Edit***

I added a direct reference to wmp.dll in nuget package. But I dont know if I can rely on this when I will make my project an executable.
[Visual Studio error message when adding the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URrwr.png)
That's my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Presentation\Form1.cs">
        <SubType>Form</SubType>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Up3.5" Version="1.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="WMPLib" Version="1.0.0">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Interop.WMPLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\.nuget\packages\wmplib\1.0.0\lib\Interop.WMPLib.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Include="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationCore.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>

    
    
</Project>
```

Comment: is the class library .net framework compatible to the project framework? check it first

Comment: @princessbubbles15, from looking at my `.csproj` file I understood they are comptible. Or there is other way to check that?

Comment: @HansPassant, I have added screenshot of the error and the content of file `.csproj`.

Comment: The error message in the question title is caused by the PresentationCore reference.  You can't use legacy .NETFramework references in a .NETCore/.NET5 project.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796358/how-to-add-wpf-support-to-net-5-winforms-project).